# Automatic logout Windows Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, logout

I have a Windows Form application made it in VB.NET 2010 and now I need to implement an automatic logout.
I'm thinking in to use a timer that is reset it with every event or save the timestamp of the every action performed by the user, the question is How I can detect every event.

The Application have several controls created on running time and some child Windows form.

Or maybe somebody have a better idea about how to meet that goal.(Logout the user from the application after some inactivity time.

---

**Edit:**
Code by Anthony converted from C# to VB

```
Class MessageFilter
    Implements IMessageFilter
    Public Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As Message) As Boolean
        Const WM_KEYDOWN As Integer = &H100
        Const WM_MOUSELEAVE As Integer = &H2A3

        Select Case m.Msg
            Case WM_KEYDOWN, WM_MOUSELEAVE
                ' Do something to indicate the user is still active.
                Exit Select
        End Select

        ' Returning true means that this message should stop here,
        ' we aren't actually filtering messages, so we need to return false.
        Return False
    End Function
End Class
```

I tried this code inside WinForm Class and in a separate Class with the same results.
"Class 'MessageFilter' must implement 'Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As Message) As Boolean' for the interface 'System.Windows.Forms.IMessageFilter'."

**Solved:**
The error in the conversion was in the Function signature that must be as follows.

```
Public Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message) As Boolean Implements System.Windows.Forms.IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage
```

**Edit 2:**
To remove the filter I declare the Filter this way

```
Public Class Form1 
  Friend MyMsgFilter As New MessageFilter()
End Class
```

Then, when I need to add the Msg Filter

```
Application.AddMessageFilter(MyMsgFilter)
```

and when need to remove it

```
Application.RemoveMessageFilter(MyMsgFilter)
```

Many thanks to Anthony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a message filter and responding to certain types of frequent messages. Sample code is C#, but it shouldn't be hard to translate to VB.NET.

```
class MessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        const int WM_MOUSELEAVE = 0x02A3;

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
            case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
                // Do something to indicate the user is still active.
                break;
        }

        // Returning true means that this message should stop here,
        // we aren't actually filtering messages, so we need to return false.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Somewhere in your application, after the user signs in, you can register the message filter using the [Application.AddMessageFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
Application.AddMessageFilter(new MessageFilter());
```

The example is only listening for [KeyDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [MouseLeave](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) events, which should both occur frequently enough, but not so frequently that the message filter is slowing down the whole application. There are a whole lot of messages being fired in a WinForms application, and doing something for every single message being sent would not be a good idea.

Comment: I convert the code and I'm getting one error "Class 'MessageFilter' must implement 'Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As Message) As Boolean' for the interface 'System.Windows.Forms.IMessageFilter'." Another doubt is Where do you get the Msg codes(hexa numbers)? I want to change MOUSELEAVE by CLICK.

Comment: The error make it look like you're not translating it to VB.NET properly. Hard to tell without seeing your code. The windows message codes can be found easily by searching online. [Here is a complete list of them](http://wiki.winehq.org/List_Of_Windows_Messages) and you can search the specific message such as [WM_LBUTTONDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There isn't such a thing as a `Click` message because it is really just a response to a MouseDown followed by a MouseUp.

Comment: When the User logout I must to dispose the MessageFilter, because if not I get one new MessageFilter by every login, so How I must do it? I know I must use Application.RemoveMessageFilter() but What I must write between parenthesis? How to reference the MessageFilter?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I detect every event?

You don't really need *every* event. A few strategic events, like `MouseMove` and some well-chosen `KeyDown` handlers should cover it. What I'd do in those events is just update a global timestamp variable, and nothing more. Then I'd also have a timer that fires every so often and checks how long since the timestamp.

Comment: I already tried that, but only fires if the mouse moves over the Form and my application have a lot of controls that use a lot of the Form surface like DataGrids and/or TabControls, so if the user leaves the mouse over someone of that control that method will logout the user even if the user still been using the program. And the application have to much control to add that code to every one.

Comment: @E_Blue Look into the `Application.AddMessageFilter` which allows you to basically hook into all messages. I would still advice only to update a time (or restart a timer) on certain types of events because the message filter will get called **frequently** and doing anything potentially intensive would slow down your application.

Comment: Thanks. That will capture all the messages even the messages from the controls created on running time? What about the messages from controls like Timers? I have a couple of Timers to update the DataGrids time to time. There's some property to distinct those messages from the user activity?

Comment: I posted an answer to better demonstrate, but a message filter will be able to listen to all messages in the system. Technically not all events spawn from a message, but many of them do.

Comment: I add the code to the original question, the IDE remarks IMessageFilter in the second line.